# SP initiated SSO not working with Google Waffle SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, google-workspace, pingone

We are trying to do SAML SSO with Google workspace as Idp and PingOne as SP connection.
we have added the SP initiated url in Gooogle connection Start Url
The SSO works fine when we initiate the SSO using SP initiated URl.

However,when we initiate the SSO from Google waffle, we are getting error at PingOne side the Application Id is missing or invalid.

I think when we initiate SSO from Google waffle, Google is doing Idp initiated SSO instead of SP initiated Url.

are we missing any part of configuration.

Is there a way we can achieve SSO from Google waffle.

Also, do we have bookmark app in google workspace like we have in OKTA

We have tried removing the start url from Google Saml connection.

Comment: SO is a site for programming issues. Your description sounds like you have a configuration issue. As is, your question is a subject to closing. If you, on the other hand, include **debugging details** which in this particular case means you include your SAML messages passed in the correct scenario vs these passes in the incorrect scenario, perhaps someone could take a look at it. Regards.